# append multiselect dropdownlist to array

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

i have dropdownlist filled with data from database i used Jquery to have multiselect option.

i want to append the checked values to array so i can insert it to the database. how can i do it using jquery or c#?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $('[id*=lstAteend]').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true
        });
    });
</script>

<asp:ListBox ID="lstAteend" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" Width="150px"></asp:ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shree/4q5og57q/2/)

I add a save button for sample to get all selected value :

```
<input type="button" id="btnget" value="Save" />
```

and On jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#teams').multiselect();

 $('#btnget').click(function() {
    alert($('#teams').val());
  })
});
```

You Get a selected value in comma separator.